# why my Modal Component is not Displaying the Confirm button nor it is forwarding the events to App.Sevlte?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

Hi I am learning Svelte and stumbled upon this problem. I have a confirm button using slots I am trying to put that in my Modal component. But it is not showing up. Also I am trying to forward the event when you click `Close` button in the Modal component. But nothing is happening. Ideally the Event should be captured and console out in the browser. Here are my Two components

`app.svelte`

```js
<script>
  import Modal from "./Modal.svelte";
  import Product from "./Product.svelte";
  let modalDisplay = false;
  let products = [
    {
      id: "24",
      title: "cat",
      subtitle: "animal",
    }
  ];
  function eventAddCart(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
    console.log("---------");
  }

  function eventDelete(event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
  }

  function handleModalClose(event) {
    console.log("================");
    console.log(event.detail);
  }
</script>

<h1>This is a product</h1>

<!-- createEventDispatcher -->

{#each products as product}
  <Product
    {...product}
    on:add-to-cart={eventAddCart}
    on:my-delete={eventDelete}
  />
{/each}

<button on:click={() => (modalDisplay = true)}>Display modal</button>

{#if modalDisplay}
  <Modal on:close-my-modal={handleModalClose} >
    <h1 slot="header">My Markup</h1>
    <!-- <p>This is what is wanted</p> -->
    <!-- <p>Allow me </p> -->
    <button slot="footer">confirm</button>
  </Modal>
{/if}

<style>
  h1 {
    color: purple;
  }
</style>
```

`Modal.svelte`

```js
<script>
  import {createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte';

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
  // export let modalDisplay = false;

  function closeModal(){

    dispatch("close-my-modal");

  }
</script>
<div class="backdrop" />
<div class="modal">
  <header>
    <!-- add marked slot here -->
    <slot name="header" />
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <!-- add unmarked slot here -->
    <slot />
  </div>

  <footer>
    <button onclick={closeModal}>Close</button>
    <slot class="footer">
    </slot>
  </footer>
</div>

<style>
  .backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .modal {
    padding: 1rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10vh;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    max-height: 80vh;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    overflow: scroll;
  }

  header {
    border-bottom: 4px #c23535;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You set a `class` instead of the `name` here:

   ```html
   <slot class="footer">
   </slot>
   ```

   So that is just another instance of the `default` slot.
2. That is not a Svelte event handler and thus will not work:

   ```html
   <button onclick={closeModal}>
   ```

   It should be [`on:click`](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#on-eventname).